# If a Service Bus Topic message is deadlettered, is it removed from all Subscriptions?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

Suppose I have a Service Bus Topic with two filtered Subscriptions, A and B. Let's say we receive a message that is visible through both of the subscriptions. If a webjob picks up the message and sends it to the dead letter from Subscription A, will it be removed from Subscription B as well? Do Service Bus Topics have separate dead letter queues?

I couldnt find documentation on this behavior.

Answer (score 3):

Conceptually each subscription is a separate queue.  Messages sent to the topic are delivered to all the subscriptions.  Each subscription stores a copy of the message, and has its own dead letter queue.

[Overview of Service Bus dead-letter queues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dead-letter-queues)

> Azure Service Bus queues and subscriptions for topics provide a
> secondary subqueue, called a dead-letter queue (DLQ).

Comment: If each subscription acts as a queue, shouldn't the message stay in that queue until a receiver connects? I'm seeing messages getting dead-lettered when the receiver service is down.

Comment: Failures in the receiver service may involve failed attempts to dequeue and deliver a message, which will trigger posion message handling. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dead-letter-queues#maximum-delivery-count